# Run hello world program on any comuter with same operating system

Tags: c++, windows, installation

Consider the situation like this. I wrote a "hello world" program on c++ and want to run this program on any computer with operating system window 7 (for example).
As I understand, the .exe file, generated by the compiler depends on my processor. And it will not necessarily run on other computer.
The question is, what should I do?

Comment: Write the same program in Python? :)

Comment: You clearly understand wrong. If what you say were true, it would be pretty difficult for any of the millions of Windows applications to exist, because they'd all have to be compiled for every single difference in processor (AMD vs. Intel, 32-bit vs 64-bit, etc.), where in fact almost all Windows desktop applications simply use the x86 32-bit platform as the target and they run on 64-bit processors as well, whether they're Intel or AMD.

Comment: You can do what other companies do and list your system requirements on the product package and any other related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the operating system is Windows, I suppose the .exe file generated must work on any other computer. In theory, the compiler does not depend upon the processor, it is designed to work independently on any platform.

Comment: But the generated object might depend on the runtime or the standard libraries if these weren't linked statically.

Comment: There is the issue of 64-bit processors versus 32-bit processors.  Also the memory limits and external devices may differ.